# Simple Injector Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, code-behind, simple-injector

Okay so I have a UI layer and a BLL layer.

```
namespace BLL 
{
   public class User : IUser
   {
        public void DoSomething(){}
   }
   public interface IUser
   {
        void DoSomething();
   }
   public static class TypeRegistry
   {
        public static void RegisterTypes(Container container)
        {
            container.Register<IUser, User>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
        }
    }
}

namespace UI
{
     public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
          private IUser user;
     }
}
```

I can't figure how to get user to not be null. I have tried making a constructor but that caused an error

```
    public Login(IUser user){ this.user = user;}
```

Compilation Error : Login does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: Have you configured ASP.NET to use your Dependency Injection framework? And have you properly configured the DI framework to handle dependencies for ASP.NET?

Comment: I have added the simple injector package if that is what you mean. But I know simple injector injects the object into constructor, but in the UI you cant have a constructor

Comment: You need to initialize the `user` field on an event of the page. Take a look at the [page lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx) and determine which event is appropriate (probably `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`) for your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link helped me get the answer:

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wpfintegration.html

Similar to @Steven's link

https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/windowsformsintegration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you've done all the registration appropriately as demonstrated in the [Web Forms integration guide of the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webformsintegration.html), then I think the problem is due to you setting the IUser accessibility level in your page to `private`.

So `private IUser user;` should become `public IUser user;`. Since Web Forms requires you to do property injection over constructor injection, the property user should be publicly accessible to be injected.